# Is it possible to save a window layout in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

When I am working with files on my project I normally have four windows open viewing four different folders in the four quadrants of the screen. My morning ritual involves having to manually open these four folders, takes only a few moments but I was hoping to find a way to automate this with Windows XP?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a batch file with these commands:

```
start c:\myfolder1
start c:\myfolder2
start c:\myfolder3
start c:\myfolder4
```

or, since Bart said in the comments on this answer, he uses this method:

```
explorer c:\myfolder1  (etc...)
```

and then run that any way you wish (on Start up, via a shortcut...)

As for saving their position on the screen, I don't know much about that, but you could try using [Winsplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/). That will let you use hotkeys to reposition windows (Ctrl+Alt+Numpad 7 moves a window to the top left).

Comment: Actually, since Windows remembers the folders' window positions, this may be good enough to open the windows in their previous size and position.

Comment: Since I've had some weird problems with "start" and a folder's name (sometimes it just opens a new cmd window), I prefer `explorer c:\foldername` instead of "start".